# AWS Athena catalog other than Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena, hive-metastore, aws-glue-data-catalog

It's known that AWS Athena comes integrated with AWS Glue for data catalog. Is there any way to configure Athena to use a different catalog e.g. to point to a different Hive metastore (e.g. on EC2 instances) managed by user?

Comment: See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connect-amazon-athena-to-your-apache-hive-metastore-and-use-user-defined-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Athena integration with a Hive Metastore is a new feature, now available in preview mode. You can find the details of how to use this feature in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-to-data-source-hive.html).